# How do I give a CodeSource to scripts which I evaluate through nashorn?

Tags: java, security, nashorn

I have a problem where some fairly trivial code running under nashorn is looking up a system property. Looking up the system property fails with an `AccessControlException`.

My security policy already permits:

```
grant {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
};
```

On debugging with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure`, I found that the `CodeSource` was `null` for the offending `ProtectionDomain`.

I moved breakpoints into the constructor for that and after a few more layers of indirection, I eventually managed to track my issue down to `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Source`.

```
private Source(String name, String base, char[] content, URL url) {
    this.name = name;
    this.base = base;
    this.content = content;
    this.length = content.length;
    this.url = url;
}
```

There is a public constructor which `NashornScriptEngine` is calling which ultimately sets the url to `null`, which is the constructor I see my code passing through.

```
public Source(String name, char[] content) {
    this(name, baseName(name, (String)null), content, (URL)null);
}

public Source(String name, String content) {
    this(name, content.toCharArray());
}
```

Although we do pass the script in as a string, it's extracted from the code blocks of an HTML file, so theoretically I *could* provide it a `CodeSource`. Then hopefully the access control code would at least give it the minimum level of trust and looking up system properties should hopefully work.

I see other constructors which *do* pass a URL along. e.g.:

```
public Source(String name, URL url, Charset cs) throws IOException {
    this(name, baseURL(url, (String)null), readFully(url, cs), url);
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how I would interact with `ScriptEngine` to encourage the nashorn engine to call one of these better constructors. `ScriptEngine#eval` only has methods which take `String` or `Reader`. Is there a way to do this? Is there another way to ensure the CodeSource is properly set when nashorn creates code?

I know what it isn't - setting the `FILENAME` in the script context. That seems to be completely ignored.

Oddly, we also run all the same sorts tests under JRuby, but we don't see the same problems over there. So whatever is going on here, this must be particular to nashorn. (FWIW, we never saw this happen under Rhino, either.)

Answer (score 2):

Providing a `CodeSource` is a security capability. Attackers could use that to falsely claim that the JS code comes from a privileged location and thus put it into any protection domain. Nashorn will only associate a `CodeSource` with code it loads itself through a URL (and thus can be certain where it came from). Even in Java, associating code with its source is something that only class loaders are allowed to do, hence it is guarded by the `createClassLoader` runtime permission. [Its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html) even says:

> "This is an extremely dangerous permission to grant. Malicious
>   applications that can instantiate their own class loaders could then
>   load their own rogue classes into the system. These newly loaded
>   classes could be placed into any protection domain by the class
>   loader, thereby automatically granting the classes the permissions for
>   that domain."

Replace "class" with "script" and you have the same concern here.
I could sort-of see Nashorn having a constructor that takes both a `CodeSource` and a `char[]`, but it'd have to do either a permission check for `createClassLoader` or a new bespoke runtime permission.

Comment: I found that nashorn loading code itself (loading its own bootstrap scripts) was passing in a null CodeSource for that case as well. It was something that tripped me up in the debugger before I found it doing the same for my own script. :)  But I also saw it doing fancy tricks with doPrivileged to set specific permissions even for those ones, which was interesting. (Deliberately reducing its own privileges in case there is a bug, I gather.)

Comment: Yes, we tend to use `doPrivileged()` with as reduced privileges as possible. Successful exploits usually depend on a chain of steps to escalate privileges, and we consciously try to break as many links in such chains as possible :-)

Comment: The Groovy scripting engine assigns codesource URLs with a "groovy:" scheme: this is extremely useful for custom security policies to identify ProtectionDomains of classes loaded from Groovy scripts. It would be extremely useful to have Nashhorn do the same; having a codesource doesn't in itself grant any privileges, it just allows security managers to identify the source of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.URLReader ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/URLReader.html ) which wraps a URL as a Reader. With a URLReader, nashorn will load script from that URL and associate proper CodeSource - so that your security policy for that URL will be effective.

Comment: That said your policy associates read permission any code. (even untrusted code). That works for me with jdk 1.8.0 update 40.

Answer (score 1):

File: Main.java

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        System.out.println(e.eval("java.lang.System.getProperty('foo.bar')"));
    }
}
```

File: foo.policy

```
grant {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
};
```

Command:

javac Main.java

java -Djava.security.manager -Dfoo.bar=sss -Djava.security.policy=foo.policy Main

"sss" is printed as expected (with jdk 1.8.0 update 40)

Comment: That code throws java.security.AccessControlException for me, but I'm on JDK 1.8.0 update 05, which might be the important difference...